# Configure postman locally in hyper-V

Tags: postman, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I'm using Hyper-V to learn about Postman and Dynamics 365. I'm currently trying to consume a service that I created in D365FO through Postman, but I am unable to do so. I think I am missing some configuration but I can't figure out what it is. Does anyone know how to configure Postman locally on hyper-V without using the Azure portal?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the steps from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test)? If you still have troubles, please update your question with your configuration steps and provide any error messages or codes you encounter.

Comment: I don't have Azure to have the tenant or client id, I'm using Postman locally in a Hyper-V environment. Is there something I can do to avoid this step and test my service?

Comment: Also, I have this error

{
    "Message": "Authentication failed.",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}

Comment: Since the authentication is done outside of your local vm against the Azure Active Directory, you still need an Azure Application to call web services of D365FO. I'm afraid, without that, you won't be able to test your service.